Unable to find user input in list
I'm trying to take user input and find it in a list of items.
I can move to a location succesfully, and I can ask a player what they want to pick up.
When the code gets to if ask in myPlayer.location.items[item.name]: I get the following error.
#MARK: Imports
import sys

#MARK: Classes
class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, name, location, job):
        self.name = name
        self.location = location
        self.job = job
        self.inventory = []
        self.gameOver = False

class Room(object):
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description
        self.exits = {}
        self.items = []

class Item(object):
    def __init__(self, name, description):
        self.name = name
        self.description = description

class Job(object):
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = name
        self.health = health

#MARK: Locations

yourHouse = Room("Your House", "This is your small house. Nothing has changed here")

townHall = Room("Town Hall", "This is the Town Hall. Sometimes people gather here to make decissions for the town")

townPark = Room("Town Park", "This is the towns small Park.\nThere is a small pond with a park bench on it's edge where you can sit and feed the ducks.\nA few trees provide shade.")

townGeneralStore = Room("The General Store", "The General Store is the largest building in town. Here you can buy almost everything you need.")

#MARK: Exits

yourHouse.exits = {'north': townHall, 'west': townPark}
townHall.exits = {'south': yourHouse, 'west': townGeneralStore}
townPark.exits = {'east': yourHouse, 'north': townGeneralStore}
townGeneralStore.exits = {'south': townPark, 'east': townHall}

#MARK: Jobs

fighter = Job("Fighter", 40)
sneak = Job("Sneak", 20)


#MARK: Create player

myPlayer = Player("", yourHouse, "")

#MARK: Create items
shovel = Item('Shovel', "You find a sturdy shovel. It looks like it could do some good bashing.")
stick = Item('Stick', 'You find a fragile looking stick, it looks like it could break easily.')

#MARK: Place Items
townHall.items.append(shovel)
townPark.items.append(stick)

print('\n' + myPlayer.location.name)
print(myPlayer.location.description)
room_exits = "\n" + "The exits are: \n"
for character in room_exits:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
for exit in myPlayer.location.exits:
    print(exit)
#MARK: Main game loop
while myPlayer.gameOver is False:
   # Start player in their house

    
    action = input('>')
    plaAction = action.lower()
    
    # Movement
    if plaAction in ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west']:
        if plaAction in myPlayer.location.exits:
            myPlayer.location = myPlayer.location.exits[action]
            print("\n" "You went to " + myPlayer.location.name + '.')
            print("\n" + myPlayer.location.description)
        for exit in myPlayer.location.exits:
            print(exit)
    
    # Pick up items
    if plaAction in ['get']:
        ask = input("What would you like to pick up?\n")
        print(type(ask))
        print(type(myPlayer.location.items))
        for item in myPlayer.location.items:
            if ask in myPlayer.location.items[item.name]:
                myPlayer.inventory.append(ask)
                print('You have picked up the ' + ask)
                print(myPlayer.inventory)
    
    # Exit Game command
    if plaAction == 'exit':
        myPlayer.gameOver = True

When the code gets to if ask in myPlayer.location.items[item.name]: I get the following error. Looking up how to check a string in a list the results show that this should be possible.
enter image description here

For the line of code
if ask in myPlayer.location.items[item.name]:

the error in not in in, the error is in here myPlayer.location.items[item.name]
This is because myPlayer.location.items is a list and item.name is a string. You can not use string as an index for list.
What you probably meant is this:
    ask = input("What would you like to pick up?\n")
    print(type(ask))
    print(type(myPlayer.location.items))
    for item in myPlayer.location.items:
        if ask == item.name:
            myPlayer.inventory.append(item)
            print('You have picked up the ' + ask)
            print(myPlayer.inventory)

Notice the line if ask == item.name:, it checks if the user input is equal to some item name among the location's items. Then you do myPlayer.inventory.append(item) to put the item into the inventory (instead of ask, which is just a string).
